When Linking Materials One of My Objects Loses Its Material?
there!  I am following Blender Guru's Donut tutorial and during part 8 when I try to link materials between my long sprinkles and my round sprinkles my round sprinkles lose their material and turn pink.
I thought that I was following exactly but apparently I did something wrong.  Can anyone fill me in please on why this is happening?  When he does what appears to be the same steps his randomized colors reflect across both is donuts where as mine only affects the long sprinkles.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

I assume he's using a GN tree to store some attribute to give the sprinkles a random color? Do all these objects also have that GN modifier as well?
